# Is there any way to see the content of an index mysql?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table like:

```
| employee | CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `age` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `age_idx` (`age`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10001 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Here I have created an index called "`age_idx`", I have 10000 records in this table, Is there any way I can see how the index store the pointers of records?

Comment: There is no standard tool for that, but it is covered in the more technical documentation .. and source. The "pointers" and entire (B-tree variant) structure are an implementation detail. All you need to know is that it means a tuple (or set of tuples) can quickly derived from a sargable operation on `age`. The *query plan* will show when/if such an index is used in a particular query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SHOW INDEX FROM employee;
```

And then a lot of reading on cardinality (is high cardinality on your first index value better of worse in case of a btree, etc).

You can not see the actual content or content distribution of the index.

Comment: I was just curious about content of the index, thanx for info.

Answer (score 0):

Your table in ENGINE=InnoDB.  You have two keys.

`PRIMARY KEY(id)` is "clustered" with the data in a B+Tree.  That is, all the data is arranged in order by `id`.  (See the Wikipedia entry for BTree.)

Each "secondary key" (such as your KEY `age_idx` (`age`)) is constructed this way.

1. Tack on the rest of the PRIMARY KEY columns.  Now it is `(age, id)`.
2. Build a B+Tree with just those columns.

Consequences:

- Any query needing only `age` and `id` can be handled entirely in the secondary index.  This is a "covering index" The EXPLAIN gives this clue: `Using index`.
- To look up something by age (and not 'covering'), first there is a BTree lookup and scan in the secondary index, then there are repeated lookups by `id` in the PRIMARY KEY / Data BTree.
- A "range" scan by the PRIMARY KEY (seems unlikely for `id`) is very efficient because it is simply accessing consecutive entries in the B+Tree.

Important characteristics of a B+Tree:

- Very efficient to find one item.  O(log(n))
- Very efficient to scan -- the 'next' and 'prev' item are essentially adjacent in the tree.
- Rule of Thumb: The fan-out is 100; there are 100 items in a "block".  (This can vary from 1 to maybe 1000; 100 is usually "close enough".)  An InnoDB block is 16KB.

Your particular fields are excessively large:

- `id` BIGINT SIGNED takes 8 bytes.  MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED (3 bytes, range 0..16 million) is probably a better choice for "employee".
- `age` INT SIGNED takes 4 bytes and allows negative ages and ages past 4 bilion.  TINYINT UNSIGNED (1 byte and 0..255) is more than sufficient for anyone living today.

There is a bunch of overhead in any InnoDB BTree; so the byte counts above are probably low by a factor of more than 2 when estimate how much disk space the index (or data) will take.